# AFNetworking uploading form data with integer

Tags: ios, django, afnetworking

I'm trying to upload a file with various data, including integers. I am doing it as per below:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"send_image" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
{        
    NSUInteger user_id_int = [tempUserID integerValue];
    NSData *user_id = [NSData dataWithBytes:&user_id_int length:sizeof(user_id_int)];
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSaved);

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data1 name:@"file" fileName:@"name.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:user_id name:@"ID" ];

}];
```

When I send the above request, the backend (which I wrote in Django) gives an error for clearing the form saying `Enter a whole number` for the ID. How can I send an integer via this form request? All other parts of the form are working.. I tried to create an NSString, however, it seems to not like when i convert an integer to a String and send it via the form request..

Comment: Try `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", integer]`...

Comment: It needs to be of `NSData` format. I'll try that too

Comment: then `[theFormattedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.

Comment: yep, did that, and it worked! interesting, though. Previously I was doing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", integer]` and it didnt work...

Comment: they're equivalent, that should work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you obtain serialized data from an integer number:

```
NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theInteger] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: i honestly have no idea why `%i` fails...but as long as it works with `%d`!